# How do I set the Remember Token in Laravel with Google OAuth

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, google-oauth

The title pretty much sums it up. I'm having trouble using `Auth::attempt` when authenticating users with Google.

I tried putting the following on my User class, but it didn't seem to work.

```
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->some_field;
}
```

Is there a way to manually set the remember token? Or is there a way to tell Laravel to look at a different field for the password?

I'm going to attempt to extend `Auth::();` We'll see how that goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out. I did a few things.

**1. Create an App/Extensions folder and created a new class in that folder.**

The new class `ExampleAuthProvider extends EloquentUserProvider`

The tricky part here was sifting through older questions and documentation to get the right list of classes to use. Here's my list.

```
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher as HasherContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as UserContract;
use Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider;
```

**2. I rewrote `retrieveByCredentials()` and `validateCredentials()`**

Here is `retrieveByCredentials()`:

```
public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
{

    $query = $this->createModel()->newQuery();

    foreach ($credentials as $key => $value) {
        if (! Str::contains($key, 'value_to_replace_password')) {
            $query->where($key, $value);
        }
    }
    
    return $query->first();
}
```

and `validateCredentials()`:

```
public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
{
    $plain = $credentials['value_to_replace_password'];

    if ($plain != $user->getAuthPassword()) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Now, this is just functional, but I need to implement hashing on this new field, and if you look at `EloquentUserProvider`s method for `validateCredentials()`, you'll see that it does a hash check.

**3. Create a new service provider.**

`php artisan make:provider YourNewServiceProvider`

In the boot method, do the following, based on the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/extending#authentication).

```
public function boot()
{
    Auth::extend('customAuth', function($app)
    {
        return new OAuthProvider(new User);
    });
}
```

Once I add the hash method back in, I'll also pass `new Hasher` to `OauthProvider`.

Make sure to import your classes.

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher;
use App\User;
use \Auth;
use App\Extensions\OAuthProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
```

**4. add your service provider to config/app.php**

`App\Providers\CustomAuthProvider::class,`

I probably should have included Service in the provider name.

I think that's everything. It was an interesting experience. Also, I will be the first to admit that I'm a very new developer, and maybe I messed something up.