# Laravel 4.2 | Auth attempt ignore active status

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm using laravel 4.2 auth system, trying auth with the next command:

```
Auth::attempt(['email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password'), 'active' => true], true)
```

The problem is that I'm trying to sign in with user that marked as non-active in the database - the the response is `true`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify Auth::attempt awhile back in order to use a Google ID for an internal project at my old job.

Basically, you need to extend the attempt method in order to add your active status to the attempt check.

[Here's my solution to the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32784520/how-do-i-set-the-remember-token-in-laravel-with-google-oauth/32786901#32786901)